# Integrating Cognitive Speech Service for both Text-to-Speech and Speech-to-Text in Microsoft BotFramework WebChat

Tags: javascript, angular, botframework

I want to integrate both speech-to-text and text-to-speech with the BotFramework WebChat

I have integrated the Speech-to-Text part of the code, but I am not able to add the Text-to-Speech

Also, I tested it in the Azure Portal "Test in WebChat" option and the speech output works

```
public async ngOnInit()  {
        const directLine = window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
            secret: "<<webchat secret>>", // from azure portal under channel webchat
            webSocket: false
        });
var ponyfillFactory = await window.WebChat.createCognitiveServicesSpeechServicesPonyfillFactory({ subscriptionKey: '<<subscriptionKey>>', region: "westus" });

        window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
            {
                directLine: directLine,
                userID: "USER_ID",
                locale: "en-IN",
                styleSet,
                webSpeechPonyfillFactory : ponyfillFactory
            },
            this.botWindowElement.nativeElement
        );

         directLine
            .postActivity({
                from: { id: "USER_ID", name: "USER_NAME" },
                name: "requestWelcomeDialog",
                type: "event",
                value: "token"
            })
            .subscribe(
                id => console.log(`Posted activity, assigned ID ${id}`),
                error => console.log(`Error posting activity ${error}`)
            );
    }
```

This is my data response from the bot has both speak and text field

```
{
  "CalendarWelcomeMessage": {
    "replies": [
      {
        "text": "Welcome to Calendar Skill! I can provide you an overview of your meetings today, read out your upcoming meeting, or create a new meeting for you.",
        "speak": "Welcome to Calendar Skill! I can provide you an overview of your meetings today, read out your upcoming meeting, or create a new meeting for you."
      }
    ],
    "suggestedActions": [
      "What are my meetings today?",
      "What is my next meeting",
      "I want to set up a meeting ",
      "Can you update a meeting ",
      "Can you cancel my event"
    ],
    "inputHint": "expectingInput"
  },
  "HelpMessage": {
    "replies": [
      {
        "text": "I can provide you an overview of your meetings today, read out your upcoming meeting, or create a new meeting for you.",
        "speak": "I can provide you an overview of your meetings today, read out your upcoming meeting, or create a new meeting for you."
      }
    ],
    "suggestedActions": [
      "What are my meetings today?",
      "What is my next meeting",
      "I want to set up a meeting",
      "Can you update a meeting",
      "Can you cancel my event"
    ],
    "inputHint": "expectingInput"
  },
  "GreetingMessage": {
    "replies": [
      {
        "text": "Hi!",
        "speak": "Hi!"
      },
      {
        "text": "Hi there!",
        "speak": "Hi there!"
      },
      {
        "text": "Hello!",
        "speak": "Hello!"
      }
    ],
    "inputHint": "acceptingInput"
  },
  "GoodbyeMessage": {
    "replies": [
      {
        "text": "Goodbye!",
        "speak": "Goodbye!"
      }
    ],
    "inputHint": "acceptingInput"
  },
  "LogOut": {
    "replies": [
      {
        "text": "Your sign out was successful.",
        "speak": "Your sign out was successful."
      },
      {
        "text": "You have successfully signed out.",
        "speak": "You have successfully signed out."
      },
      {
        "text": "You have been logged out.",
        "speak": "You have been logged out."
      }
    ],
    "inputHint": "acceptingInput"
  },
  "FeatureNotAvailable": {
    "replies": [
      {
        "text": "This feature is not yet available in the Calendar Skill. Please try asking something else.",
        "speak": "This feature is not yet available in the Calendar Skill. Please try asking something else."
      }
    ],
    "inputHint": "acceptingInput"
  },
  "CancelMessage": {
    "replies": [
      {
        "text": "Ok, let's start over.",
        "speak": "Ok, let's start over."
      }
    ],
    "inputHint": "acceptingInput"
  }
}
```

Comment: There have been changes related to the Speech for the 4.5 release which might be causing this issue. Now the 4.5.0 version is out and you can try testing the text-to-speech. In the meanwhile, if you want to test the text-to-speech feature, you can test it against the [latest bits](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#how-to-test-with-web-chats-latest-bits).

Answer (score 0):

If you have integrated Speech-To-Text, your bot will automatically try to reply with Text-To-Speech, but you have to ensure that *on your bot side* you provide a `speak` value in your Activity in addition to `text` value.

Comment: JSON data from where the response is read, It has both text and speak field, also I can see the voice response when I test it in the Azure portal but not while in my code